# Change the size of OS X terminal using keyboard

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

When typing in a terminal on OS X, I'd like a way to resize the window I'm typing in without taking my hands off the keyboard. Is there an easy way to do this? If not, any ideas for hacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) to configure keyboard shortcuts for resizing and moving windows:

```
bind right:ctrl,alt resize +50 0
bind left:ctrl,alt resize -50 0
bind up:ctrl,alt resize 0 -50
bind down:ctrl,alt resize 0 +50
```

You might also use [xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
printf '\e[8;24;80t' # resize to 80x24
printf '\e[3;0;0t' # move to top left corner
printf '\e[9;1t' # maximize
printf '\e[9;2t' # maximize vertically
printf '\e[9;3t' # maximize horizontally
```

or AppleScript:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to tell window 1' -e 'set b to bounds' -e 'set item 3 of b to (item 1 of b)+500' -e 'set bounds to b' -e end`

Answer (score 1):

Command+ will make the window and the text larger, that's about as good as you're going to get from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Although <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> does change window size, font is scaled as well.

Using Magnet to reposition a resized window maintains font size.

This can be done as follows:

1. Open a terminal and scale window: <kbd>⌘
   Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>
2. Reposition window to top left of screen:
   <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
3. Repeat as needed

**Note:** I'm unaware of any keyboard shortcuts to adjust font size alone.